# Add a second onChange event?

Tags: javascript, onchange

Hi I found this script online that adds an onChange event to an element and I would like to now add a second onChange event to the same element. Heres the script:

```
document.getElementById('piname').onchange =
function() {
    removeChildren({
        parentId: 'account_table',
        childName: 'extraaccount'
    });
}
```

And the onChange event i want to add is:

```
showAccount(this.value)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `addEventListener()` (and `attachEvent` as a fallback, if needed).
Example:

```
document.getElementById('piname').addEventListener("change", function(e){
  e = e || event;
  showAccount(e.target.value);
}, false);
```

Example, with fallback:

```
var element = document.getElementById('piname');
if(element.addEventListener){
  element.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    e = e || event;
    showAccount(e.target.value);
  }, false);
}
else if(element.attachEvent){
  element.attachEvent("onchange", function(e){
    e = e || event;
    showAccount(e.target.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Reduce your element lookups by storing the result from `getElementById` in a variable.  Also, `this` is correctly bound to the element for `addEventListener`.

Comment: Hmm @Andy @Digital im getting the following error...`uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)" location: "JS frame`

Comment: @Jonah, add `false` as the last argument in `addEventListener`. FireFox complains about it, Chrome and Safari don't.

Comment: @Zanfa: yeah, that's correct upto and including Firefox 5.  It's optional in Fx 6.

Comment: @Zanfa @Andy @Digital Ok now its working beautifully in FF, but in IE i get this error: `Object doesn't support this property or method` referring to the line `document.getElementById('piname').addEventListener("change", function(e){`

Comment: @Jonah use the second example, it has a fallback for IE using the attachEvent.

Comment: @Zanfa Perfect! Just an fyi, it gave me an error concerning target.value so i cha

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to cache the old function and call it from the new one:

```
var el = document.getElementById('piname'),
    old = el.onchange;

el.onchange = function () {
    old.call(el);
    showAccount(this.value);
}
```

Other than that, you could use `addEventListener` (W3C standards) and `attachEvent` (IE8 and lower):

```
var el = document.getElementById('piname'),
    fn = function (e) {
         e = e || window.event;
         showAccount((e.target || e.srcElement).value); 
    };

if ("addEventListener" in el) {
    el.addEventListener("change", fn, false);
}
else {
    el.attachEvent("onchange", fn);
}
```

Those methods allow you to attach as many handlers to events as you like.

Comment: Could you explain  old.call(el); ? edit : nvm https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call